# Texas Instruments SN502

Tags: history

My father is an engineer that worked at TI directly under Jack Kilby in the early 60’s. This chip was given to him by Kilby as a “thank you” for all his hard work. We also have the accompanying build sheet.

We believe it to be possibly the only one to still exist. We are in the process of finding a private collector who can appreciate its historical value. 
So have a look and tell me what you think. Has anyone ever seen one or know somebody who may have one?

[image: A Ti Chip]

Comment: If the part number of SN502 is correct, there's information about them at the [Computer History Museum](https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102762884). The SN502 was the first Integrated Circuit sold by TI, and is thus quite historic.

Comment: We are certainly unable to assist with estimating a monetary value.  Historical value is another matter.

Comment: I wonder if TI themselves still has one?

Comment: There is also an entry at the Smithsonian (http://smithsonianchips.si.edu/texas/t_326.htm) that suggests they have one.

Comment: Good question. I bet TI must have one tucked away somewhere. I have been in contact with TI and they are declining to get involved with any authentication efforts.

Answer (score 8):

I understand the interest in selling this so I would beg you to contact the Computer History Museum as your first attempt. This is clearly an important bit of history and should be preserved in a (semi-)public collection if possible.

Comment: Or just loan it to them indefinitely if you don't need the money right away. They will take good care of it for you.

Answer (score 3):

We have been corresponding with David Brock at the Computer History Museum and he’s very excited about the chip. Mr. Brock has requested a phone interview with my father to add to the musuem’s collection